# python IDE, code suggestion, pycharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, autosuggest

I use latest community pycharm(2016.2.3) under windows 7 with latest python 2.7.

I write a little in python but it gives me big pain with code completion.

For example:

I want to use beautiful soup library.
I installed it with pip in pycharm.
I do import: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag`

(I found about Tag here, on stackoverflow, it helps to receive more suggestions)
...
I wrote some code..

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('some link')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
texto = soup.find(id="Phone")
```

Working code written by hand:

`UNC=texto.find(text="Line Key 2").findNext('tr').findNext('tr').findNext('tr').find_all('input')[0]['name']`

Now I try to receive suggestion:
`text2=texto.` <- here I press **Ctrl+Space**

What I receive:
[image]

Let's try other suggestion test:

`text2=soup.` <- here I press **Ctrl+Space**

Ok. Here is what I receive:

[image]

There is find method, okay. Let's try this:

`text2=soup.find(id='user').` <- here I press **Ctrl+Space**

And I do not see any methods I need! Why there is no **find()** or **findNext()** in suggestion (see hand written code)?
But many other items. Why??

I really like python, but code suggestion makes me cry.

Is it possible to have code suggestion like in MS Visual Studion with C#?

Comment: hints3   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZeAd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally realized that because of dynamical typization suggestions some time could not be dynamically evaluated.  So have to read documentation and code.